# Is it possible to tell how many times an app has been opened?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Not a single app, but I'd like to be able to see how many times each of the apps on my phone have been opened. If possible, can I tell the time spent in each?

Comment: I'm asking specifically about iOS devices, namely the iPhone 4 :) sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save such things in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You just save a timestamp when the app is openend and when closed. With the appropriate AppDelegate methods.

But (of course), this might not work perfectly, if your app crashes. So you could do the same by saving in time intervals by using NSTimer

Comment: Yeah, but that's just for a specific app and I have to have the ability to edit that code. How about for existing apps on my phone that I didn't write?

Comment: ah, ok. Now I fully understand you. But I guess that won't be possible, at least if the iPhone isn't jailbroken. Than maybe you can ask the taskmanager, or `top`

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system? Do you have root access? You could just let an observer run, and protocol every minute, what is running, filter out what is not interesting, and assume something which is running for 3 consecutive minutes to be run that long, not 3 times for one minute. Ah - I see 'iphone' in the tags.